# Tomcat 9 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I've encoutered some problems with using tomcat.For some reason tomcat can't load my stylesheet.The link is defined inside the head.jsp,this file i include using the include directive in all my jsps that need the stylesheet.I found out that this problem occurs when i dispatch from Servlet to Jsp using the request.getRequestDispatcher(...).When i accessed the same file directly,the stylesheet loads normally.

Image1:

[image]

Image2:

[image]

Image3:

[image]

Image4:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing context path of project.

Case 1: Consider your current URL is `http://localhost:8585/project_name/`
Then including stylesheet with` ``href = "css/style.css"```
==> *http://localhost:8585/project_name/css/style.css*

Case 2: Consider your current URL is `http://localhost:8585/project_name/users`
Then including stylesheet with` ``href = "css/style.css"```
==> *http://localhost:8585/project_name/users/css/style.css*
404 error

So use context path as prefix, To use context path while including javascript or stylesheet use JSTL tag library and **url tag** to achieve it as given below.

Include JSTL

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Include stylesheet or scripts by using jstl url tag as given below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />" >
```

Comment: I don't get it - how is that the case?Can you explain a little?And as i said,the stylesheet loads normally if i access the file directly,but it doesn't when i use dispatcher to forward to the file.Also,i tried the url tag,and it didn't work.Here is the code i wrote:     <link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value="/css/style.css">'>

Comment: Let me know your url's before forward and after forward. Take url from browser.

Comment: At startup,my browser opens with http://localhost:8585/project_name/.I try to access simple example which is : http://localhost:8585/project_name/test.This url is mapped in web.xml to TestServlet.In the TestServlet i have this code :        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsps/test.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request,response);
After the forward my url is : http://localhost:8585/project_name/test

Comment: I think you are getting 404 when your url is http://localhost:8585/project_name/ because ```../``` forces relative path to go one folder up. so it will makes stylesheet url to http://localhost:8585/....

Comment: c:url should work from any pages no doubt about that. Paste your request.getRequestDispatcher() code

Comment: use request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getContextPath()+"/jsps/test.jsp") and let me know.

Comment: @PraveenKumarLalasangi it worked with the c url.My bad.Now i see that it uses the context path.Thank you.

Comment: What was mistake? use request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getContextPath()+"/jsps/test.jsp") ?

Comment: @PraveenKumarLalasangi The problem really was in the contex path.From now on i'll be using c:url.

Comment: @PraveenKumarLalasangi no,there is no problem with the forwarding.I guess it's the relative path.It didn't work as i expected.The c url includes the context path and works normally.Thank you.